# Decrement the value of Ticket Quantity after a purchase

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a rails web app, where I have a tickets table and it has the column 'ticket_quantity'.

Now when a person buys a particular number of tickets, lets say 5 for example, what is the best way to decrement 5 from the total tickets that I have stored in the "ticket_quantity" column and display the new ticket quantity in the 'number of tickets available section' in the view.

I know it is a noob question, but I'm not really sure what to do. I know I'm not supposed to decrement/alter the value in the db column directly as I will need the original value for stats..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a column `tickets_sold` in your purchases table, and your purchases belong_to your tickets, you can create a method in your ticket model for `ticket_quantity_available`

```
class Tickets < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :purchases

    def quantity_available
      ticket_quantity - purchases.sum(:tickets_sold)
    end

end
```

That will use the SQL sum method to add up the tickets sold and subract from the original `ticket_quantity`.  Just use the new method as needed...

```
<%= "Tickets available: #{@ticket.quantity_available} %>
```

Comment: That's almost perfect to what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic solution in case you really don't want to alter your original value:

You probably have a model that represents a purchase, in this model add an integer column "quantity". You'll just have to subtract the sum of all the "quantities" to the "ticket_quantity" value and you'll have your value.